# How to remove and reinstall Vorbis codec?

Tags: apt, dpkg, dependencies

Soundconverter crashes everytime I convert my flac files to Ogg Vorbis. I am getting the following error in terminal.

```
The following packages have unmet dependencies:
libvorbis0a : Breaks: libvorbis0a:i386 (!= 1.3.5-3) but 1.3.2-1.3ubuntu1.2 is installed
libvorbis0a:i386 : Breaks: libvorbis0a (!= 1.3.2-1.3ubuntu1.2) but 1.3.5-3 is installed
libvorbisenc2 : Depends: libvorbis0a (= 1.3.2-1.3ubuntu1.2) but 1.3.5-3 is installed
libvorbisfile3 : Depends: libvorbis0a (= 1.3.2-1.3ubuntu1.2) but 1.3.5-3 is installed
E: Error, pkgProblemResolver::Resolve generated breaks, this may be caused by held packages.
E: Unable to correct dependencies
```

Output of apt-cache policy libvorbis0a libvorbis0a:i386

```
libvorbis0a:
  Installed: 1.3.5-3
  Candidate: 1.3.5-3
  Version table:
 *** 1.3.5-3 0
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.3.2-1.3ubuntu1.2 0
        500 http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main amd64 Packages
        500 http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main amd64 Packages
     1.3.2-1.3ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/ trusty/main amd64 Packages
libvorbis0a:i386:
  Installed: 1.3.2-1.3ubuntu1.2
  Candidate: 1.3.2-1.3ubuntu1.2
  Version table:
 *** 1.3.2-1.3ubuntu1.2 0
        500 http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/ trusty-updates/main i386 Packages
        500 http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/ trusty-security/main i386 Packages
        100 /var/lib/dpkg/status
     1.3.2-1.3ubuntu1 0
        500 http://archive.linux.duke.edu/ubuntu/ trusty/main i386 Packages
```

Comment: What release of Ubuntu are you running?  Your first `libvorbis0a` reports a !=xenial  (16.04) version rule, but Trusty (14.04) package is installed.  Your sources possibly contain invalid entries.  https://packages.ubuntu.com/search?keywords=libvorbis0a

Comment: I'm running Ubuntu 14.04 LTS. Is there any way i can fix this?

Comment: Please add the output of `apt-cache policy libvorbis0a libvorbis0a:i386` to your question - ie. edit & add the output there.

Comment: I have added the output. Sorry for the poor text formatting.

Comment: you can try `sudo apt-get -f install` and see if it helps. If it doesn't `sudo apt-get remove vorbis-tools` then if needed the `sudo apt-get -f install` again.  If it then looks okay you can try `sudo apt-get install vorbis-tools`. If you have issues, you can retry with the initial 'remove' replaced with 'purge' (which removes some config too, but I doubt it'll do better).   https://packages.ubuntu.com/trusty/vorbis-tools   Your issue is because you have installed a non-Ubuntu or non-trusty version (1.5.3-3 from somewhere). If you still have issues I'll need `apt-cache policy vorbis-tools`.

Comment: My system is not booting. I am having a pop up saying “The system is running in low graphics mode”. I’ll try your solution when i’ll be able to boot.

Answer (score 0):

your 64 bit Ubuntu has 32 bit libvorbis so find a Ubuntu that 64 bit with proper libvorbis architecture and reinstall Ubuntu.